# using arrayformula to grab from different sheet dynamically

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this tables :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EPRpybVderYa7WOEyElbtQjrDUb-944zchWAR9UKYRM/edit?usp=sharing

I have 3 price tables (data01, data02, data03). In the matrix table , I want to use arrayformula to automatically grab the value of grade/supplier/price. I want each row to grab dynamically from different 'dataXX' sheet based on the value in the B2:B6 using indirect(). If the value is **02** then it shold grab from data**02** etc.

[image]

The formula I used in the matrix!D2 is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,lambda(a,b,if(or(a="",b=""),,index(ifna(vlookup(a,indirect("data"&b&"!A:D"),{2,3,4},))))))
```

[image]